# Weird rendering behavior on IE11 + Angular 1.5.11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

We're currently developing an application in Angular version 1.5.11. It has become quite big now (hundreds of controllers etc.), and we stumbled upon an issue in Internet Explorer 11:

After some time (sometimes few minutes, sometimes few hours) the page starts to have rendering glitches - the letters are fading/disappearing/changing color. It also affects other tabs opened in the same window (screenshot from the Excel Online having the same issue). Also, there are no errors in console.

Did anyone come across similar issue? Also, "just using a normal browser" is not a viable option due to client's requirements.

Restarting the browser helps, but it's more of a workaround than an actual solution.

---

Application tab (it appears on every element of the page as well, cropped for visibiltity):
[image: Application]

Excel Online tab on the same browser:
[image: Excel tab on the same browser]

Comment: no error in console ?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi - nothing

Comment: Your fonts broke. Do you use custom fonts? Have you checked the Performance tab for any anomalies?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey - we use "Lato" font, opening performance tab on IE11 (or any of dev tools in that matter) is utterly slow and takes minutes to even open. We can check it next time we encounter this bug, but it also happens on other tabse as well. Is it possible that broken font can crash the rendering engine in the whole browser?

Comment: I'm only familiar with certain font rendering issues related to some `<meta>` tag attributes. I'm not even sure if a memory leak can cause this

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, I suggest you could try to use different computer or IE 11 version (you could try to upgrade the IE 11 to the latest version) to test your code to verify whether still meet this behavior.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT - unfortunately no, because of agreement with client and huge codebase making it extremely hard to narrow down the code due to the issue's unpredictability

Comment: I had encountered such issues in IE (11 and older) when i used (1) forEach loops and (2) lambda/arrow functions... i was working on Angular 1.6x for these SPAs - give it a look, hope it helps

Comment: @Lemurr Tryout meta options explained in the link, it might work (who knows its IE!) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/turn-off-natural-metrics

Comment: I assume you've also tried this application on another machine with the same browser and exhibits same behaviour? i.e. this isn't isolated to a particular machine?

Comment: @Squiggs - happens on multiple machines with the same browser (both overseas client and us has experienced that)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this issue might be around the browser memory leak (considering that other tabs are also getting affected).

We had issues around memory leaks only in IE browser with Angular 1.3 (not the exact issue).

While this [link](https://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications/) might help you with further investigation, I'll mention how I used IE's memory profiling tool to help myself.
This memory profiling tool can be found in IE 11 dev tab.

1. Click Start Profiling.
2. Take a heap snapshot of your web app without performing any operation on your app.
3. Perform some operation and take a heap snapshot again.
4. Go back to the home page and see if some of the memory you allocated is getting freed or not.

Each heap snapshot also provides a deeper look into the objects allocated and how much memory each object is consuming.

I am attaching a snapshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: did this answer help you?

Comment: The problem is that IE freezes for over 10 minutes while opening the dev tools, and after couple of minutes of profiling it freezes again and crashes - and the issue happens after few hours. 

I believe it's because we already have hundreds (if not thousands) of JS files attached, and it cannot handle it. We'll try to profile it in Chrome though, but the memory leak is not that significant, though we will certainly look into this - thank you for the tip :)

Comment: @Lemurr I'm facing the same problem in angular 7. Did you get the solution?

Comment: @Anas - not really, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue for my Angular 7 app and I have been researching this issue for 3 days. I have inspected with any memory leakage or unwanted loops. Well, I didn't find anything specific to led this issue.
I have tested my app in different environments. This happening only for my low configured machines. By digging some solution I found this:

This might be is due to the **use of GPU rendering instead of software rendering** to view the webpage. What we need to do is just change a configuration in settings. Follow the steps below:

1. Start Internet Explorer 11.
2. Click the Tools icon in the upper-right corner, and then click Internet Options. (Alt+X).
3. Click the Advanced tab, and then browse to the Accelerated graphics section.
4. Select the Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering check box.
5. Click Apply, and then click OK.
6. Close all open Internet Explorer 11 windows, and then restart Internet Explorer 11.
7. View the webpage in Internet Explorer 11.

[image]

*Note You can also resolve this issue by upgrading your video card to a video card that supports GPU hardware acceleration.*