# Weird Rendering IE 11 behaviour with Angular

Tags: angular

I am facing the same issue with IE 11 and Angular 7 as described in this post:
[Weird rendering behavior on IE11 + Angular 1.5.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376479/weird-rendering-behavior-on-ie11-angular-1-5-11/58204737?noredirect=1#comment102787736_58204737)

Has someone resolved this issue ? If yes then please let me know the solution

Comment: Would be best if you could describe the issue you are having, instead of linking to another question. The question you linked is related to AngularJS while your question is Angular.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue with Angular 7. That's why I have given link for describing the problem only difference is that in my case it is angular 7

Comment: Clarified title; reorganised content for clarity